# Filtering out Duplicates From Select Statement - SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following SELECT statement for my **sqlite3** database. It is possible that there is duplicates in one column: `name`

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, job, employer, name FROM Table
```

I only want unique values returned from name and this is why I have used the DISTINCT keyword, but if there is multiple values such as 2 "Joe" values, it will return them both. How can I just return one?

Comment: So those two Joes can have different Jobs, or different IDs? What value should be returned in that case?

Comment: If you have two rows whose `id`, `job` and `employer` are different, but the `name` are equal - which row would you return using your requirement?

Comment: @CL. It doesn't matter which is returned. I am just playing about with SQLite so I can figure out to the extent which the use can query from a GUI interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you unique name with one of values from other fields:

```
SELECT name, MIN(id) as id, MIN(job) as job, MIN(employer) as employer
FROM Table
GROUP by name
```

Answer (score -1):

The distinct should prevent sql from giving duplicates.id is you primary key I suppose.
So, write your command as
SELECT DISTINCT name, id, job, employer FROM Table